Second driven values don't get updated, in my script
Long story short, I'm encountering this issue where a driven property that depends on an output value from my script doesn't update. But this just happen when the input value is driven by another blender property.
I know it sounds confusing but let me show what works and what doesn’t:

This works fine, I can get automatic output with no problem.

This work fine too, I can get the Blender property automatically updated with a driver.


This doesn’t work, as soon as input is driven by a Blender property or is key frame it the output driver doesn’t update the final Blender property.
What I've Tried:
Implemented handlers using depsgraph_update_post and frame_change_post
Called bpy.context.view_layer.update()
Even combining all of them simultaneously
The Goal:
I'm using a CSV file stored in Blender's text editor. The script reads the CSV data and uses an input value to look up and return a corresponding output value. This output value should then drive properties in Blender, such as the Z location of an object or anything.
Everything works as expected when I manually change the input value, but when I drive the input value (e.g., using the "current frame" or keyframes), the output driven Blender property stops updating.
Clarification:
In Blender you can use drivers in properties and this properties ca be drivers of other properties and so on with no issue. So, I think I need some sort of function or workaround to force Blender to update all drivers and dependencies consistently.
Additional Context: The idea was to create a script that would allow for dynamic data-driven values that could be used in Blender properties or Geometry Nodes. Originally I was trying to make a custom geometry node with python but apparently you can’t.
I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this.


import bpy
import csv
from io import StringIO

# Function to read CSV and update the result value
def update_result_value(context):
    obj = context.object
    if not obj:
        return

    csv_data = obj.csv_data_properties
    text_block = csv_data.text

    # Read the content of the text block as CSV data
    csv_content = text_block.as_string()
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(csv_content))

    input_value = str(csv_data.value)
    output_column = csv_data.column_name

    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[csv_reader.fieldnames[0]] == input_value:  # Check the first column
            csv_data.result_value = float(row.get(output_column, 0.0))  # Get the value or default to 0.0
            return

# Handler to update drivers and call the CSV update function
def depsgraph_update_handler(scene):
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()  # Force an update to evaluate all drivers
    update_result_value(bpy.context)

# Additional handler for frame change to ensure updates on animations
def frame_change_handler(scene):
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()  # Force update on frame change
    update_result_value(bpy.context)

# Property group to hold user inputs and the result
class CSVDataProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    value: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Input Value",
        description="Value corresponding to the first column",
        default=0
    )
    column_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Output Column",
        description="Name of the column to return data from"
    )
    text: bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        name="Text",
        type=bpy.types.Text,
        description="Select a text block from the Blender file"
    )
    result_value: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Return Value",
        description="Value found in the specified column",
        default=0.0
    )

# Panel for user interface
class OBJECT_PT_CSVDataManager(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "CSV Data Manager"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_csv_data_manager"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        csv_data = obj.csv_data_properties

        layout.label(text="CSV Data Options")
        layout.prop(csv_data, "text", text="Select CSV Text")
        layout.prop(csv_data, "value")
        layout.prop(csv_data, "column_name", text="Output Column")
        layout.prop(csv_data, "result_value", text="Return Value")

# Register and unregister functions
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CSVDataProperties)
    bpy.types.Object.csv_data_properties = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=CSVDataProperties)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_CSVDataManager)
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(depsgraph_update_handler)
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(frame_change_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_CSVDataManager)
    del bpy.types.Object.csv_data_properties
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CSVDataProperties)
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.remove(depsgraph_update_handler)
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(frame_change_handler)

# Run the script
register()


Please use the python and/or scripting tag when asking about scripting.

I vote to close as "too localized". It's a bug hunt. If there's some kind of weird interaction as described in title: "Second Driven values don't get updated", then the csv part is irrelevant and should be removed from the script with a simpler device to update the values (e.g. a global variable that is being incremented). I don't think anyone else can benefit from this question.

I just want to be able to use data from CSV files. first I was trying to make a node in geometry nodes. But they told me that you can't. Then I was thinking about this approach which is not too bad. so I can use the output in geometry nodes. I use blender for engineering and I think this can be so powerful. Look I talked about it in a blender conference.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoTo-HnIvW4

I don't see exactly how they Python end of this even fits into the question. It seems like your question is just "How to get use a property with a driver as a variable in another driver". Am I wrong? Or is the python script running during playback and you want it to read a value from the CSV file based on the frame and then use that value to drive the Z location?

In blender you can run drivers and make that driver run other drivers and so on.
But here the input value is used to return an output value through a script that read data. It could be anything, an array, a list, a table, etc. in this case is a CSV file in the text editor.
And it works fine until I use a driver or set keyframes to run the input value. The output value gets outdated, yes!, but the drivers from the out put value don't.
I was thinking that this is just a matter of finding a function that update everything in Blender. But it looks like is more complicated than that
